# Obj-C: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UITextfield *_strong' from 'NSNumber *_strong

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Ok Ive looked at the other similar questions but I cant figure out why NSNumber would not be compatible with the UIText Field.

my .h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *initialBudget;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *expenses;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *timeSpent;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *incomePerHour;
```

These is my calculations

```
- (IBAction)calculateResults:(id)sender {
    double budget = [initialBudget.text doubleValue ];
    double expense = [expenses.text doubleValue];
    double time = [timeSpent.text doubleValue];

    double hourlyIncome = (budget - expense)/time;
    NSNumber *resultNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:hourlyIncome];
    incomePerHour = resultNumber;
}
```

any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set UITextField's text property.

```
[incomePerHour setText:[resultNumber stringValue]];
```

Bye !

EDIT :
You can also do it without the NSNumber :

```
[incomePerHour setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", hourlyIncome]];
```

You'll have less precision due to %f (rounds to 6 decimal by default), but you can use `%.42f` if you want 42 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

> I cant figure out why NSNumber would not be compatible with the UIText Field.

Because they are different types of objects and there is no implicit type conversion in Objective-C (aside from toll-free bridging) like there is in C++ and other languages. In fact, it wouldn't really make much sense to implicitly convert from a number object to a text field object.

What you want to do is this:

```
// Set incomePerHour text field text property with number formatted to two decimal places
incomePerHour.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", hourlyIncome];
```

P.S. To create an `NSNumber`, you can just do:

```
NSNumber *resultNumber = @(hourlyIncome);
```